Utilizing Sqlite `no such table` error in Go?
When working with the sqlite database in Go. During the testing I got the error: no such table: table_name.
Well I know where the error is coming from.
But I want to know if there is a way that I can use this error message in Go, to do some work with it(like create that table in my code). I was trying to do something like this:
_, err := getState(dbconn) // This the function that retrieves the table that does not exists
if err != nil {
    if err == err.New("no such table: table_name") {
        // do the work
    }
}


"Well I know where the error is coming from". In that cas please show the code that causes the error, as it will be more useful.

From the docs: "Each call to New returns a distinct error value even if the text is identical". Either the package you are using provides a specific error type which can be inspected, or you have to compare against the error string.

In Go, errors returned by SQLite, such as "no such table," cannot be compared to a string using err.New("no such table: table_name"). This is because the "no such table" error is returned as an sqlite3.Error object, not as a string.
To handle this error, you should check the error message using the Error() method:
_, err = getState(dbconn)
if err != nil {
    if err.Error() == "no such table: table_name" {
        fmt.Println("Creating the table")
        // do the work
    }
}

